# Assign command return value in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am using the below to count the files number which created days is older than 10 days:

```
forfiles /m *.txt /d -10 /c "cmd /c echo @path" | find /c /v "" >count.tmp
for /f %%b in (count.tmp) do @set /a count=%%b
```

is there anyway that can assign return value without save a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f %%b in ('forfiles /m *.txt /d -10 /c "cmd /c echo @path" ^| find /c /v "" ') do set /a count=%%b
```

should assign `count` to the value output from `forfiles`.

See `for/?` from the prompt for documentation. The caret before the pipe is an escape character to inform `cmd` that the pipe is *part* of the command to be executed.